# WordPress "Featured Image" Functionality Broken IIS7 Install

Tags: wordpress, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2003

We have WordPress 3.4.2 installed on a Windows Server 2003 and IIS 7 box. Moving to a x-NIX environment is not a possibility.

We have had an outside contractor come in and get MOST everything working, but there is one last problem that he has completely given up on.

Anything that tries to use the "Featured Image" functionality is broken. This includes Themes that use the "Featured Image" functionality to upload a header image, and the image thumbnails for post excerpts.

Images upload fine, but you cannot select USE AS FEATURED IMAGE when editing a post, page, or anywhere else for that matter.

We have tested with several current Themes and it doesn't seem to be Theme specific in any way.

If this were on a linux box, I would expect it to be a folder permissions issue, but I don't know where to begin troubleshooting in this IIS environment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I can provide any further info, please let me know.

AK

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. After an unbelievably annoying round of troubleshooting, I found that I did not have the graphics library extension enabled on my server. I had to uncomment the following line in my php.ini file:

extension=php_gd2.dll

Once I made that change, I restarted IIS and all featured images began displaying properly. Hope this helps!